# Initialize custom JS attached to Small Checkbox button on Experience Editor page load

Tags: experience-editor, speak, ribbon

I have created a Small CheckBox Button within Experience editor in the View tab called "ABC" checking/unchecking that injects/removes html around renderings on the page. Till now everything works fine. Now i have issue where If i go to View tab and Check "ABC" it adds sample HTML around controls than i navigate to "Home" Tab and refresh the page and My java script is not called that resides within View tab on page refresh. Although after page refresh as i click on View tab my script gets executed as I am storing the state in registry and HTML gets injected but not on page load although stored state is still there.

Can some one throw a light what can be a issue here?

Here is my sample script.

```
define(["sitecore", "/-/speak/v1/ExperienceEditor/ExperienceEditor.js"], function (Sitecore, ExperienceEditor) {
Sitecore.Commands.AddHtmlToControls =
{
    commandContext: null,
    isEnabled: true,

    canExecute: function (context) {
        if (!ExperienceEditor.isInMode("edit")
          || !context
          || !context.button
          || context.currentContext.isFallback) {
            return false;
        }

        toggleRenderingHtml(context.button.get("isChecked") == "1")
        if (!Sitecore.Commands.AddHtmlToControls.commandContext) {
            this.commandContext = ExperienceEditor.getContext().instance.clone(context);
        }

        return true;
    },

    execute: function (context) {
        ExperienceEditor.PipelinesUtil.generateRequestProcessor("ExperienceEditor.ToggleRegistryKey.Toggle", function (response) {
            response.context.button.set("isChecked", response.responseValue.value ? "1" : "0");

            toggleRenderingHtml(response.context.button.get("isChecked") == "1");

        }, { value: context.button.get("registryKey") }).execute(context);
    }
};

var toggleRenderingHtml = function (enabled) {

    if (enabled) {
       //some code logic here 
    } else {

       //some code logic here 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why on Page Load it does not trigger the JavaScript is because you need to set the `PostponedCall` value to `false`

Using Sitecore Rocks, on the rendering SmallCheckButton, view the Properties window and scroll down up to the Event Section. Then, in the field `PostponedCall`, set the value to `false`. A screenshot is provided below:

[image]

Your JavaScript methods will then get triggered even if you have click the Home Tab and the refreshes the page.

Comment: Thanks Hishaam for the help and this does sounds like an answer but for me somehow when this changes are deployed does not work and my JS it still not  called on page load except when i click on View tab. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: This did resolve the issue, till now problem was with our deployment. Many thanks Hishaam.